# PHP connect to SQL server on different machines

Tags: php, sql, iis

I have a PHP website on a Windows machine and would like to insert data DIRECTLY to SQL database which is located on IIS server on a different machine?

Which approach shall I follow?

**My initial thought was to divert to a PHP page hosted by IIS that executes a query and then redirect back to my website. However, I prefer something easier and less complicated approach.

IIS is on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Your help is appreciated very much. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using PHP, you can open a connection to a database on another machine using PDO:

```
$remotedb = new PDO("*dbtype*:dbname=*dbname*;host=*addressOfOtherMachine*", $user, $password);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Comment: Actually, the PDO connection is: `$dbh = new PDO($hostname, $username, $password);` where the `$hostname` is something along the lines of: `$hostname = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabaseName';`

Comment: I can use PDO to connect to SQL database?

Comment: @flangofas Yeah, the PDO object represents a database connection.

Comment: I would recommend using PDO over SQLSRV in this case despite my answer.  I believe there is better support and error handling for PDO.

Answer (score 1):

**I use SQLSRV in PHP to connect to a database on an IIS6 machine with 2008 R2.**  I believe the remote machine must allow remote connections and needs to be turned on through the settings if it isn't.  Here is what my connection string looks like:

```
<?php
    /* NEW CONNECTION FOR SQLSRV DRIVER (for MSSQL access) */
    $uid = "username";
    $pwd = "password";
    $DB = "database_name";
    $serverName = "ip_address_of_remote_server (example: 192.168.0.25)";
    $connectionInfo = array("UID" => $uid, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database"=> $DB, "ReturnDatesAsStrings" => true);
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
?>
```

Here is a sample **parameterized insert query** using the connection:

```
<?php
    $p1 = "values passed from a form";
    $p2 = "values passed from a form";
    $p3 = "values passed from a form";

    $params = array(
        array(&$p1, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(50)),
        array(&$p2, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_DATETIME),
        array(&$p3, null, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(50))
    );

    $sql = "INSERT INTO database_name (column1, column2, column3) values (?,?,?)";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, $params);

    if( !$stmt ) { die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); } 

    if(sqlsrv_execute( $stmt ) === false ) { die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); } 

?>
```

**For more SQLSRV params**, visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc626305.aspx